# Output re-direction when Command Line arguments are present

Tags: shell, unix, arguments, command-line-arguments, redirect

I am trying to redirect an output to output.txt after running a command like below. It has a command line argument file1.txt

`#./a.out file1.txt > output.txt`

But I am unable to redirect the the output to output.txt. The output.txt file is empty and the output is getting printed in the console itself. 
I was wondering is there another way to do this?

Comment: try #./a.out file1.txt > output.txt 2>&1. Your program may use stderr instead of stdout

Answer (score 0):

Depending on is application uses stdout or stderr for output you may need to redirect both of them to capture the output. The command

```
#./a.out file1.txt > output.txt 2>&1
```

will redirect srtout and stderr into output.txt